# Library for the Summary API (used to get summaries of webpages)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, library

I was wondering if I could get some pointers on how I can improve my library, whether it be design pattern/naming convention/or any ideas on a better implementation.

[GitHub](https://github.com/ghostiek/Summary.NET)

As it stands, I am using a builder pattern, so you'd go:

```
var sum = new Summary();
sum.ApiKey(_apikey).Url(_url);
```

Then you would get the JSON which includes the summary of the webpage like so `sum.GetJSON()`

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SummaryLib
{
public class Parameters
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int? SentenceCount { get; set; }
    public int? KeywordCount { get; set; }
    public bool? IncludeQuotes { get; set; }
    public bool? IncludeBreaks { get; set; }     
}

public class Summary
{
    private Parameters _parameters = new Parameters();

    #region Builder
    public Summary ApiKey(string _apikey)
    {
        _parameters.ApiKey = _apikey;
        return this;
    }
    public Summary Url(string _url)
    {
        _parameters.Url = _url;
        return this;
    }
    public Summary SentenceCount(int _sentencecount)
    {
        _parameters.SentenceCount = _sentencecount;
        return this;
    }
    public Summary KeywordCount(int _keywordcount)
    {
        _parameters.KeywordCount = _keywordcount;
        return this;
    }
    public Summary IncludeQuotes(bool _includequotes)
    {
        _parameters.IncludeQuotes = _includequotes;
        return this;
    }
    public Summary IncludeBreaks(bool _includebreaks)
    {
        _parameters.IncludeBreaks = _includebreaks;
        return this;
    }
    #endregion


    public async Task<string> GetJSON()
    {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder($@"http://api.smmry.com");
        url.Append(UrlBuilder(UrlParameters()));

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var responsemessage = await client.GetAsync(url.ToString()))
        using (var content = responsemessage.Content)
        {
            return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public List<string> UrlParameters()
    {
        var parameterList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in _parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (item.GetValue(_parameters) != null) parameterList.Add(item.Name);
        }

        var translator = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"ApiKey","SM_API_KEY" },
            {"Url", "SM_URL" },
            {"SentenceCount", "SM_LENGTH"},
            {"KeywordCount", "SM_KEYWORD_COUNT"},
            {"IncludeQuotes","SM_QUOTE_AVOID" },
            {"IncludeBreaks","SM_WITH_BREAK" }
        };

        var parsedUrlParameters = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in parameterList)
        {
            parsedUrlParameters.Add(translator.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item).Value);
        }

        return parsedUrlParameters;

    }
    public string UrlBuilder(List<string> urlParameters)
    {
        var urlDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"SM_API_KEY", _parameters.ApiKey},
            { "SM_URL", _parameters.Url },
            {"SM_LENGTH", _parameters.SentenceCount},
            {"SM_KEYWORD_COUNT", _parameters.KeywordCount},
            {"SM_QUOTE_AVOID", _parameters.IncludeQuotes},
            {"SM_WITH_BREAK", _parameters.IncludeBreaks }
        };

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder($"?");
        foreach (var item in urlDictionary)
        {
            if(item.Value != null) builder.Append($"{item.Key}={item.Value}&");
        }           
        return builder.ToString();
    }

}
}
```

Explanation of the code:

The `UrlParameters` method uses reflection to get a list of which parameters were provided and assign the proper url variables (example:"SM_API_KEY","SM_URL" ect...).

The `UrlBuilder` method will create the actual url by including the variables from the `UrlParameters` function and the variables inputted by the user.

[Example query](http://api.smmry.com?SM_API_KEY=1234&SM_URL=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus)

My rubber duck told me that I don't need the `UrlParameters` method to make this work. Regardless, I still feel like I shouldn't use a dictionary like I have in `UrlBuilder`.

Comment: Congratulations on fixing your question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Improvables

- `Parameters` - the class name is too general, it should be `SmmryParameters`
- `Summary` - this class is doing way to much. It not only builds the query string but also downloads the data. You need to separate it.
- Parameter names and query string names should be closer together, I mean use attributes to specify query string names. You also repeat each property name as a dictionary keys as a string. This is a really bad idea. You should at least use the `nameof`.

## Example

Here's how it could look like and let's with the attribute that will store the query string name of one parameter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class SmmryParameterAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _name;
    public SmmryParameterAttribute(string name) { _name = name; }
    public override string ToString() => _name;
}
```

Then you decorate each property with this attribute:

```
public class SmmryParameters : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    [SmmryParameter("SM_API_KEY")]
    public string ApiKey
    {
        get => (string)this[GetSmmryParameterName()];
        set => this[GetSmmryParameterName()] = value;
    }

    [SmmryParameter("SM_URL")]
    public string Url
    {
        get => (string)this[GetSmmryParameterName()];
        set => this[GetSmmryParameterName()] = value;
    }

    [SmmryParameter("SM_LENGTH")]
    public int? SentenceCount
    {
        get => (int?)this[GetSmmryParameterName()];
        set => this[GetSmmryParameterName()] = value;
    }

    [SmmryParameter("SM_KEYWORD_COUNT")]
    public int? KeywordCount
    {
        get => (int?)this[GetSmmryParameterName()];
        set => this[GetSmmryParameterName()] = value;
    }

    [SmmryParameter("SM_QUOTE_AVOID")]
    public bool? IncludeQuotes
    {
        get => (bool?)this[GetSmmryParameterName()];
        set => this[GetSmmryParameterName()] = value;
    }

    [SmmryParameter("SM_WITH_BREAK")]
    public bool? IncludeBreaks
    {
        get => (bool?)this[GetSmmryParameterName()];
        set => this[GetSmmryParameterName()] = value;
    }

    private string GetSmmryParameterName([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        return
            GetType()
                .GetProperty(propertyName)
                .GetCustomAttribute<SmmryParameterAttribute>()
                .ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"?{string.Join("&", this.Select(item => $"{item.Key}={item.Value}&"))}";
}
```

At the same time you use a little compile trick with the `CallerMemberName` to get the property name and based on this the actual query string name that will be the key of the dictionary that the `SmmryParameters` class is derived from.

It also overrides the `ToString` method to generate the query string.

Lastly you need a downloader to get the data:

```
public class SmmryDownloader
{
    public async Task<string> GetJsonAsync(SmmryParameters smmryParameters)
    {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder($@"http://api.smmry.com");
        url.Append(smmryParameters);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var responsemessage = await client.GetAsync(url.ToString()))
        using (var content = responsemessage.Content)
        {
            return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the method's name is now `GetJsonAsync` because by convention we add the `Async` suffix to `async` methods.

This is not a bullet-proof solution if you want to access the properties manually because it will throw if a key does not exist. You might want to use `TryGetValue` if you need to but it'll do for the current scenario otherwise you should implement the getters this way:

```
get => TryGetValue(GetSmmryParameterName(), out object value) ? (string)value : default(string);
```

### Usage

```
var smmryParams = new SmmryParameters
{
    ApiKey = "123",
    Url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus"
};

var smmryDownloader = new SmmryDownloader();
json = smmryDownloader.GetJsonAsync(smmryParams);
```

## Testing

In order to be able to test it you can create an interface for the downloader and use it to create another mock-downloader.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to use that! Time to learn attributes :D

Answer (score 0):

Url Builder is may be like this..

```
    public string UrlBuilder()
    {
        var translator = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"ApiKey","SM_API_KEY" },
            {"Url", "SM_URL" },
            {"SentenceCount", "SM_LENGTH"},
            {"KeywordCount", "SM_KEYWORD_COUNT"},
            {"IncludeQuotes","SM_QUOTE_AVOID" },
            {"IncludeBreaks","SM_WITH_BREAK" }
        };
        var  parsedUrlParameters = _parameters.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.GetValue(_parameters) != null)
            .Select(p => string.Format("{0}={1}", translator[p.Name], p.GetValue(_parameters)))
            .ToArray();
        return "?"+ string.Join("&", parsedUrlParameters);

    }
```

update:

You do not really need both UrlParameters() and Parameters class. You can handle with Dictionar

```
public class Summary
{
//private Parameters _parameters = new Parameters();
private Dictionary<string, object> _parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

#region Builder
public Summary ApiKey(string _apikey)
{
    _parameters["SM_API_KEY"] = _apikey;
    return this;
}
public Summary Url(string _url)
{
    _parameters["SM_URL"] = _url;
    return this;
}
public Summary SentenceCount(int _sentencecount)
{
    _parameters["SM_LENGTH"] = _sentencecount;
    return this;
}
public Summary KeywordCount(int _keywordcount)
{
    _parameters["SM_KEYWORD_COUNT"] = _keywordcount;
    return this;
}
public Summary IncludeQuotes(bool _includequotes)
{
    _parameters["SM_QUOTE_AVOID"] = _includequotes;
    return this;
}
public Summary IncludeBreaks(bool _includebreaks)
{
    _parameters["SM_WITH_BREAK"] = _includebreaks;
    return this;
}
#endregion


public async Task<string> GetJSON()
{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("http://api.smmry.com");
    url.Append(UrlBuilder());

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var responsemessage = await client.GetAsync(url.ToString()))
    using (var content = responsemessage.Content)
    {
        return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}


public string UrlBuilder()
{
    var parsedUrlParameters = _parameters
            .Select(p => string.Format("{0}={1}", p.Key, p.Value))
            .ToArray();
    return "?" + string.Join("&", parsedUrlParameters);
}
}
```